# Thymeleaf: Loop iteration in <div> tag and create rows.

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new in `thymeleaf`, and trying to iterate values using `thymeleaf` `th:each` attribute, but get wrong output. I am using `<div>` instead of table, when thymeleaf render the page, all objects values override the first row values and rest of the rows are empty show. Following is my code:

My Spring MVC controller code

```
ProductCategory category = new ProductCategory();
category.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(558711));
category.setTitle("Category 1");
category.setStatus(FinEnum.STATUS.IN_ACTIVE.getStatus());

ProductCategory category2 = new ProductCategory();
category.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(558722));
category.setTitle("Category 2");
category.setStatus(FinEnum.STATUS.ACTIVE.getStatus());

List<ProductCategory> categories = new ArrayList<ProductCategory>();
categories.add(category);
categories.add(category2);

model.addAttribute("categories", categories);
return "admin/product/view-categories";
```

My thymeleaf code:

```
<div class="row-area" th:each="category: ${categories}">
                    <div class="column2 tariff-date" style="width: 15%;"><span th:text="${category.id}">Dummy Data</span></div>
                    <div class="column2 tariff-date" style="width: 15%;"><span th:text="${category.title}">Dummy Data</span></div>
                    <div class="column2 tariff-date" style="width: 13%;"><span th:text="${category.status}">Dummy Data</span></div>
                    <div class="column5 icons middle-area" style="margin-left: 7px; width: 40%;">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="diplay-none"></a>
                        <a class="icon7" href="javascript:void(0)" style="width: 140px;">View Sub Category</a>
                        <a class="icon2" href="javascript:void(0)"><p>Edit</p></a>
                        <div th:switch="${category.status}" style="margin-left: 195px;">
                            <a class="icon8" href="javascript:void(0)" th:case="'Inactive'" style="width: 88px;">Deactivate</a>
                            <a class="icon9" href="javascript:void(0)" th:case="'Active'">Active</a>
                        </div>
                        <a class="icon14" href="javascript:void(0)" style="width: 60px;"><p>Delete</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My Output is:

[image]

Comment: Can you try it first remove  <div th:switch part because it is starting to fail at that point.

Comment: hello @erhun i already try this, but still getting this output.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has nothing to do with Thymeleaf, it's just a simple typo.  After the line:

```
ProductCategory category2 = new ProductCategory();
```

you are still modifying (overwriting) the `category` object instead of `category2`.  Therefore, the properties of `category2` never got set.  Corrected code should be:

```
category2.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(558722));
category2.setTitle("Category 2");
category2.setStatus(FinEnum.STATUS.ACTIVE.getStatus());
```

Tested this locally and saw we "rows" of data after the fix.

Comment: Yes, @Martin i found the answer already. Thanks for your answer.