# How to assign the id of a selected <option> element to another variable for further processing ? ThymeLeaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm completely editing the original question sience I've got an answer in this post that gave me some guidance:

I've got this ThymeLeaf template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/app.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <select name="gustos" id="selectGustos">
        <option th:each="gusto : ${gustos}" th:text="${gusto.nombre}" th:value="${gusto.id}"> </option>
    </select>
    <div class="row delete">
        <div class="col s12 l8">
            <form th:action="@{'/gustos/' + ${gusto.id} + '/delete'}" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="button">Borrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the `<form>` I'm doing a post with the variable **${gusto.id}** that's not being binded to anything (and not working properly).

What I need to do is bind the selected `<option>`'s id value to the form's **${gusto.id}** variable so that my controller then know's which id needs to be deleted.

So basically I need the selected `<option>`'s (which it will be an Object of type Gusto) id attribute to travel in my `<form>` to my controller.

The controller is expecting an **int** as the id !!

Comment: You need to add a parameter to your action url `th:action="@{/gustos/{id}/delete(id=${gusto.id)}"` something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... now I'm getting this error: Could not parse as expression: "@{/gustos/{id}/delete(id=${gusto.id)}" (deleteGusto:18)

Comment: The problem is your `form` isn't inside the `th:each`... So you probably need either some javascript or make the select part of the form and submit the `id` to delete as a parameter instead as part of the path.

Comment: Thanks bro, it was solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use `jquery` for this. In fact, I believe it would be the easiest solution for your current issue. This way, you will always have the correct `id` in the action url.

```js
$('#selectGustos').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#gustosForm').attr('action', 'gustos/' + value + '/delete');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/app.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <select name="gustos" id="selectGustos">
        <option value="-1" selected="selected">Escoger Gusto</option>
        <option th:each="gusto : ${gustos}" th:text="${gusto.nombre}" th:value="${gusto.id}"> </option>
    </select>
    <div class="row delete">
        <div class="col s12 l8">
            <form id='gustosForm' th:action="@{'/gustos/' + ${gusto.id} + '/delete'}" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="button">Borrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I added an `id` to your form, so that it would be easier to fetch it's value. One more thing, you should add a default option in the beginning of your select, so that the user can't choose a wrong value.

Comment: This is more what I wanted !! I'll try it out! Thanks Alan <3

Comment: Hope it works! Let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 1):

Add `th:action="@{/gustos/{id}/delete(id=${gusto.id})}"` like this.

Refer [thymeleaf-construct-url-with-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938344/thymeleaf-construct-url-with-variable) and [standardurlsyntax-thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#adding-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... now I'm getting this error: Could not parse as expression: "@{/gustos/{id}/delete(id=${gusto.id)}" (deleteGusto:18)

Comment: Thanks brother ... now I have this error: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "gusto.id" (deleteGusto:18) !!! Why is this so anti-logic ?

Comment: iterate gustos before <form th:action="@{/gustos/${gusto.id}/delete}" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="button">Borrar</button>
            </form>

Comment: I'm guessing it is because it doesn't knows to which id I'm refering to. Sience the id in the <option> is comming from the th:each gusto in ${gustos} but the id in the form might be in a different scope ? Then the question might be how to get the selected gusto.id from the selected <option> to be passed to the form for then posting to my controller

Comment: you can create a outer div which will serve to select and form both. so iterate gustos inside that div.  <div th:each="gusto: ${gustos}">

Comment: Can you put it in code if you have time ?? Sorry, I'm pretty new to this

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560999/thymeleaf-loop-iteration-in-div-tag-and-create-rows

Comment: sorry,i cant do that. please accept and upvote the answer if it has given the solution of main problem. otherwise everything is new question actually.

Comment: Should I delete the question then ? Cause the answer is not solving my problem, even thought it helped for know-how

Comment: Initiate a new question instead of deleting this.

Comment: plz help, I'm stuck with this :(

Answer (score 0):

```
th:onclick="'javascript:consultar();'"

<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function consultar() {

  var gustoId = $("#selectGustos option:selected").val();

    $.ajax({

        url: "/gustos/"+ gustoId + "/delete}",
        success: function(response) {

        }
    });         
}
</script>`
```

Comment: thanks, updated the question sience the problem is not in there

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand where the problem is.
Is your select working correctly?

Comment: Is it the problem sending the form?

Comment: Yes, the problem is sending the form with the selected options's id being the variable that makes it dinamic !

Comment: I need to get the id of the selected option, and then concatenate it in the th:action so it travels in the post

Comment: The problem for me is here: th:action="@{'/gustos/' + ${gusto.id} + '/delete'}" , you should do th:action=" '@{/gustos/'+${gusto.id}+'/delete}' "

Comment: That's not the prob ... the prob is the id !! It doesn't knows to which id I'm reffering to, and I don't know how to tell the template to get the id of the selected option in the <select>

Comment: I understood, to solve this I think you will have to use ajax

Comment: If you decide to use ajax tell me that I will help you